# InvalidOperationException in Fsharp.Core.dll

Tags: winforms, f#, invalidoperationexception

So I am doing a simple personal project in winforms with F#. My code used to work, but now throws this exception for seemingly no reason.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in FSharp.Core.dll

 Additional information: The initialization of an object or value resulted in an object or value being accessed recursively before it was fully initialized.
```

The code is a member method that is being invoked from the constructor of the form itself

```
    do
 //lots of other constructor code before this point
 // render the form
        form.ResumeLayout(false)
        form.PerformLayout()
        form.ReloadGoals



//several other members before here
    member form.ReloadGoals  =
        let x = 10  //crashes on this line
```

The website where I grabbed the template for the project I am using is [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2011/05/27/f-windows-application-template-for-winforms.aspx).
Unfortunately I have made some substantial additions to this.

I would be glad to post more code, but I need to know what code would be relevant exactly, as I am not exactly sure and don't want to bog down the post in extraneous code.

Also I can't really find a lot of documentation on System.InvalidOperationException.
Every time I find it, it is being used as [an example](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/exceptions/) of an exception [you can throw on your own](https://books.google.com/books?id=66jOWQEvBMEC&pg=PA64&dq=F%23%20invalidoperationexception&hl=en&sa=X&ei=k7OSVL3tM4XggwTngoSgBQ&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=F%23%20invalidoperationexception&f=false), not what causes it.

Comment: Could you be running into this problem? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182331.aspx

Comment: I appreciate the idea. I don't have any virtual methods that I am calling from the constructor. They are all implemented. Even if some are pretty much place holders with () as the method body.

Comment: Within the constructor code are you passing `form` to any other of your type's constructors? This can cause the exception you are seeing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [The F# 3.0 Language Specification (final version, PDF)](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/3.0/FSharpSpec-3.0-final.pdf), *§8.6.1  Primary Constructors in Classes*:

> During construction, no member on the type may be called before the last value or function definition in the type 
>   has completed; such a call results in an *InvalidOperationException.*

Almost certainly, your code in the question doesn't tell the full story. If you hit the above 
mentioned restriction, then there's somewhere an attempt to access a field or member not fully initialized.

Some example:

```
type X() as this =
    let x = this.X
    member __.X = 42
X()
```

One workaround might be to encapsulate the offending code in a member of its own and call that in the constructor instead. Another would be the wrapping in a function definition.

Comment: This was the issue. Not sure what you mean by encapsulate in this case. It seems to be that no member will be fully loaded before the constructor finishes because of the way F# types have to be set up, sectioning it off within an another member and running it from the constructor seems to be the problem in the first place.

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett As long as the member is called after the `last value or function definition`, you should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

This will be an incomplete answer, since I cannot reproduce the problem (using F# interactive, the given example, the ReloadGoals modification, and `Form.Show`, the code runs fine). However, there are strange things happening:

- Taken from the template, there should be a handler method for the [Form.Load event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which fires when the type is fully constructed. Why is additional loading code in the constructor instead of this event handler? `Load` exists precisely to counter this kind of problem with unorderly initialization.
- The template you are using isn't exactly sane F#. For example, `initControls` is a value of type unit that is evaluated where it is defined; its binding to a name is absolutely useless and should be replaced with a simple `do`. Writing `initControls` in the `do` block later has no effect at all. `form.ResumeLayout(false); form.PerformLayout()` should be equivalent to `form.ResumeLayout(true)`, but I don't understand what these are doing in the constructor in the first place. The event handlers have two possibly unnecessary indirections: one to a delegate constructor, another to a method that has no real reason to exist -- the handlers should be lambdas or simple, private functions. Why are they public members?!

The error appearing in the question is probably caused by the usage of `form` in its own constructor. Move your new usage to the `Load` event handler, and it should work.

Personally, I would go further and ditch implementation inheritance by instantiating a plain `Form` and subscribing to its events. For example, in FSI, something similar to the template could be done like this:

```
open System.Drawing
open System.Windows.Forms

let form = new Form()
form.ClientSize <- new Size(600, 600)
form.Text <- "F# Form"

let formLabel = new Label()
formLabel.Text <- "Doubleclick test!"
formLabel.DoubleClick.Add <| fun _ -> form.Close() 
form.Controls.Add(formLabel)

form.Show()
```

which uses no inheritance at all. (In an application, you'd use `Application.Run` etc instead of `form.Show()`.) This does not run into initialization problems as easily and, additionally, is very useful if you want to encapsulate the form inside a simpler type or even just a function.